# ForeignKey para cada usuario logado

Tags: python, django

Quando eu vou cadastrar uma atividade mostra  a chave/campo(ForeignKey) de todos os usuario. Eu queria que mostrasse a chave/campo apenas do usuario logado não de todos alguem ajuda?

```
class Campo(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    descricao = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name="Descrição", null=True, blank=True)
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} ({}) [USER:{}]".format(self.nome, self.descricao, self.usuario)


class Atividade(models.Model):
    numero = models.IntegerField()
    descricao = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name="Descrição", blank=True)
    pontos = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, max_digits=4, null=True)
    detalhes = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    chave = models.ForeignKey(Campo, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} - {} ({})".format(self.numero, self.descricao, self.chave.nome)



Tentei fazer fazer a filtragem no forms mas n da para fazer exempo: Campo.objects.filter(usuario=self.request.user)

class chaves(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Atividade
        fields = ['numero','descricao', 'pontos', 'detalhes','chave']

    def __init__(self,  *args, **kwargs):
        super(chaves, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['chave'].queryset = Campo.objects.filter()
```

Comment: Essa seleção de campo tem que ser no Admin Template, ou pode ser um html? exemplo https://imgur.com/iGRd69N

Comment: Seria no template. Tipo ta mostrando a ForeignKey de todos os usuarios ao inves de mostra apenas da pessoa logada e eu so usando form no template exemplo: https://imgur.com/a/g3KfHrb

Comment: Beleza, entendi. Vou mandar uma solução no template html, pode ser?

Comment: Ta obrigado pela ajuda